# When $108n^4+1$ is a perfect square if $n$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to find which integers values of $n$ makes $108n^4+1$ a perfect square

One solution is $n=0$, and I already proved that $n$ is not odd, I believe that the only solution is $n=0$, is there a counterexample?

If $n$ is odd, $108n^4+1$ would be congruent $5$ modulo 8 and that is impossible for it to be a perfect square.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $108=27\cdot 4,$ so this question is asking for solution to $u^2-3v^2=1$ where $v$ is  $6$ times a perfect square. We know how to solve $u^2-3v^2=1,$ by Pell's equation. We get a recursive sequence $(u_n,v_n).$ You might be able to prove recursively that $v_n$ is never $6$ times a perfect square.

Comment: You are interested in the sequence $(X_1,Y_1), (X_2,Y_2), \cdots$ where $(X_1,Y_1) = (7,4)$ and $$\left[X_k + Y_k\sqrt{3}\right] = \left(7 + 4\sqrt{3}\right)^k$$ and $Y_k$ has form $(6n^2).$  Superficial examination gives the sequence $$(7,4), (97,56), (1351,780),\cdots.$$ Superficially, this one does not seem to be a walk in the park.

Comment: For what it's worth, re previous comment, the actual primitive solution is $(2,1)$.  However, if you examine the sequence formed by $$\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)^k,$$ you will see that for each odd positive integer $(k)$, the resulting value $(R_k,S_k)$ will have an odd 2nd component, $S_k$.  This is why attention may be restricted to $$\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)^{2k} = \left(7 + 4\sqrt{3}\right)^{k}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there's an $n \neq 0$ solution, and have $n_1 \gt 0$ be the smallest such positive integer solution (note this answer will show there must be a smaller value).

First, any perfect square that $108n_1^4+1$ is equal to must be odd, so as this [deleted answer](/a/4557709) indicates, it is of the form $(2x+1)^2 = 4x^2 + 4x + 1$ for some integer $x \gt 0$. We therefore get

$$27(4)n_1^4 + 1 = 4x^2 + 4x + 1 \; \; \to \; \; 27n_1^4 = x(x + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $\gcd(x, x+1) = 1$, there are $2$ cases to consider for some positive integers $u_1$ and $v_1$. First, $x = u_1^4$ and $x + 1 = 27v_1^4$, so then $u_1^4 + 1 = 27v_1^4$. However, if $u_1$ is even (so $v_1$ is odd), then $0 + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, while if $u_1$ is odd (so $v_1$ is even), then $1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, so this case cannot be true. Thus, it must be the second case of $x = 27u_1^4$ and $x + 1 = v_1^4$, with this giving

$$27u_1^4 + 1 = v_1^4 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

If $u_1$ were odd (so $v_1$ were even), we have $3 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$. Thus $u_1$ is even (so $v_1$ is odd), i.e., $u_1 = 2u_2$ for some integer $u_2 \gt 0$. Also, $v_{1}^2 = 2y+1 \; \to \; v_{1}^4 = 4y^2+4y+1$ for some integer $y \gt 0$. Thus, \eqref{eq2A} becomes

$$27(16)u_2^{4} + 1 = 4y^2 + 4y + 1 \; \; \to \; \; 27(4)u_2^{4} = y(y+1) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Similar to before, since $\gcd(y, y+1) = 1$, there are $4$ cases to consider for some positive integers $u_3$ and $v_3$:

**Case** $1$: $y = u_3^4$ and $y + 1 = 4(27)v_3^4$

This gives $u_3^4 + 1 = 4(27)v_3^4$. Thus, $u_3$ is odd, so $1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, which is not true.

**Case** $2$: $y = 4u_3^4$ and $y + 1 = 27v_3^4$

We then have $4u_3^4 + 1 = 27v_3^4$, which means $v_3$ is odd, so $0 + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, which is not possible.

**Case** $3$: $y = 27u_3^4$ and $y + 1 = 4v_3^4$

This results in $27u_3^4 + 1 = 4v_3^4$. Note integers to the $4$'th power are congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $5$. If $5 \mid u_3$, the LHS is congruent to $1$ mod $5$ while the RHS is congruent to $4$ instead (since $5 \not\mid v_3$ due to $\gcd(u_3,v_3)=1$). However, if $5 \not\mid u_3$, then the LHS is congruent to $3$ mod $5$, while the RHS is congruent to $0$ or $4$. Thus, this case is also not possible.

**Case** $4$: $y = 4(27)u_3^4$ and $y + 1 = v_3^4$

We get

$$4(27)u_3^4 + 1 = v_3^4 = (v_3^2)^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note this is of the same form as the original Diophantine equation. However, we have $u_{1}v_{1} = n_1$ and $v_1 \gt 1$, so $u_1 \lt n_1$. Also, $u_1 = 2u_2$, so $u_2 \lt u_1$. Next, $u_{3}v_{3} = u_2$ and $v_3 \gt 1$, so $u_3 \lt u_2$. Combining these gives $u_3 \lt n_1$. However, $u_3$ is a positive integer, so $n_1$ can't be the smallest such solution. This contradiction shows this case can't be true either.

---

None of these $4$ cases being possible means there is no positive integer $n$ solution, i.e., $n = 0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **long-winded** comment.  
**This is not an answer.**

First of all, I am repeating the comments that I left, after the posted question.

The primitive solution to $X^2 - 3Y^2 = 1 $ is $(X,Y) = (2,1).$  
All solutions $(X,Y)$ are generated by the formula

$$\left(X_k + Y_k\sqrt{3}\right) = \left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)^k ~: k \in \Bbb{Z^+}. \tag1 $$

As a necessary and sufficient condition of the problem, you are looking for a value $(X_k,Y_k)$, generated by (1) above, where $Y_k$ has form $(6n^2).$  This is because $(108n^4)$ can be re-expressed as $3 \times \left( ~6 ~\left[n\right]^2 \right)^2.$

The next element in the sequence, generated by (1) above is $(X_2,Y_2) = (7,4).$  Note that this element is of form $(A,B)$, where $A$ is odd and $B$ is even.

If you consider any such expression

$$\left(A + B\sqrt{3}\right) \times \left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right) ~: ~A ~\text{odd}, ~B ~\text{even},$$

you will see that the result is

$$\left(2A + 3B\right) + \sqrt{3}\left(2B + A\right),$$

where $(2A + 3B)$ is even and $(2B + A)$ is odd.

Then, if you take any expression of the form

$$\left(R + S\sqrt{3}\right) \times \left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right) ~: ~R ~\text{even}, ~S ~\text{odd},$$

you will see that the result is

$$\left(2R + 3S\right) + \sqrt{3}\left(2S + R\right),$$

where $(2R + 3S)$ is odd and $(2S + R)$ is even.

---

This means that if you examine the sequence formed by (1) above, the elements in that sequence will have form

$$\left(\text{even}, ~\text{odd}\right), ~\left(\text{odd}, ~\text{even}\right), ~\left(\text{even}, ~\text{odd}\right), ~\left(\text{odd}, ~\text{even}\right), \cdots .$$

Since the 2nd component $Y_k$ is required to be of form $6n^2$, it is required to be even.  Therefore, when examining the sequence of elements generated by (1) above, all such elements generated when $k$ is an odd positive integer may automatically be rejected.

Therefore, you are looking for some elements $R_k,S_k$ generated by

$$\left(R_k + S_k\sqrt{3}\right) = \left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)^{(2k)} = \left(7 + 4\sqrt{3}\right)^k. \tag2 $$

The first three elements of the sequence generated by (2) above are

$$(7,4), ~(97,56), ~(1351,780).$$

---

At this point, in desperation, my analysis goes in the following direction:

The $S_k$ component generated by

$$\left(R_k + S_k\sqrt{3}\right) = \left(7 + 4\sqrt{3}\right)^k$$

may be computed as

$$\sum_{i \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~i ~\text{odd}, ~i \leq k} \left[ ~\binom{k}{i} \times 7^{(k - i)} \times 4^i \times 3^{[(i-1)/2]} ~\right]. \tag3 $$

Examining the terms expressed in (3) above, you see that whenever $i \geq 3$, then the term is a multiple of $(3)$.  Further, the first term,

$$\binom{k}{1} \times 7^{(k-1)} \times 4^1$$

will be a multiple of $(3)$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $(3)$.

Therefore, attention may be restricted to the elements generated by the formula in (2) above, with $k$ required to be a multiple of $(3)$.

This implies that you may restrict your attention to elements generated by

$$\left(U_k + W_k\sqrt{3}\right) = \left(1351 + 780\sqrt{3}\right)^k. \tag4 $$

(4) above is as far as my thinking takes me.  I see no simple way of demonstrating that none of the elements generated by (4) above will have a 2nd component $W_k$ of form $6(n^2).$